# How to programmatically adjust image width to fit in a linear layout using TouchImageView?

Tags: java, android, touchimageview

I am programmatically inserting a touch image view in a linear layout.If I use a normal image view the image adjust's itself when the orientation changes.But when I started using touch image view the image shrinks to a very small size.This is the code that I am trying to implement :-

```
 TouchImageView imageView = new TouchImageView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            imageView.setMaxZoom(4f);
            web_linearLayout.addView(imageView);

            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setScaleType(TouchImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                imageView.setCropToPadding(false);
            }

            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/reckoner_images/" + fileName)));
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: This is because it is maintaining its aspect ratio. Try to put inputType : fitXY in xml.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Nidhi. I tried this  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); but it did not work.

Comment: why is this property set ? imageView.setMaxZoom(4f);

Comment: @Stallion I am using a class called TouchImageView for adding zoom effect on image's.It sets the max  zoom.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the method `setImageURI` to load image, the image will be scaled according to the density of device. The statement `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);` will make the dimension of original `ImageView` auto scale when you set its LayoutParams with `WRAP_CONTENT` (you can read the source of the method 'onMeasure' in `ImageView`). However, `TouchImageView` overrides method `onMeasure` to implement extra function, which cause the `setAdjustViewBounds` useless (also you can read the source of method `onMeasure` in `TouchImageView`). So the dimension of `TouchImageView` can not auto scale. You can do as following:

Use `setImageBitmap` instead of `setImageURI` to load image and process scaling by youself.

```
 //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/reckoner_images/" + fileName)));
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/reckoner_images/" + fileName);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Or use `MATCH_PARENT` instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` in the LayoutParams of `TouchImageView`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

I have tested it by myself, which is useful. Hope it can solve your problem:)